# Trying to sort two different columns of a text file, (one asc, one desc) in the same awk script

Tags: linux, awk, associative-array, asort

I have tried to do it separately, and I am getting the right result, but I need help to combine the two.
This is the csv file:

```
maruti          swift       2007        50000       5
honda           city        2005        60000       3
maruti          dezire      2009        3100        6
chevy           beat        2005        33000       2
honda           city        2010        33000       6
chevy           tavera      1999        10000       4
toyota          corolla     1995        95000       2
maruti          swift       2009        4100        5
maruti          esteem      1997        98000       1
ford            ikon        1995        80000       1
honda           accord      2000        60000       2
fiat            punto       2007        45000       3
```

I am using this script to sort by first field:

```
 BEGIN { print "========Sorted Cars by Maker========"
 }
 {arr[$1]=$0} 
 END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_desc"                       
        for(i in arr)print arr[i]
        }
```

I also want to run a sort on the year($3) ascending in the same script.
I have tried many ways but to no avail.
A little help to do that would be appreciated..

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output; it's not clear (to me) if you want the primary sort on the 1st field (and secondary sort on the 3rd field), or vice versa ... so seeing the expected output will help clarify the requirement

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- individual fields do not contain white space
- primary sort: 1st field in descending order
- secondary sort: 3rd field in ascending order
- no additional sorting requirements provided in case there's a duplicate of 1st + 3rd fields (eg, `maruti` + `2009`) so we'll maintain the input ordering

One idea using `sort`:

```
sort -k1,1r -k3,3n auto.dat
```

Another idea using `GNU awk` (for arrays of arrays and `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`):

```
awk '
    { cars[$1][$3][n++]=$0 }                     # "n" used to distinguish between duplicates of $1+$3
END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"
      for (make in cars) {
          PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
          for (yr in cars[make])
              for (n in cars[make][yr])
                  print cars[make][yr][n]
      }
    }
' auto.dat
```

Both of these generate:

```
toyota          corolla     1995        95000       2
maruti          esteem      1997        98000       1
maruti          swift       2007        50000       5
maruti          dezire      2009        3100        6
maruti          swift       2009        4100        5
honda           accord      2000        60000       2
honda           city        2005        60000       3
honda           city        2010        33000       6
ford            ikon        1995        80000       1
fiat            punto       2007        45000       3
chevy           tavera      1999        10000       4
chevy           beat        2005        33000       2
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine and it's an easy explanation. Can you tell me one thing : the line PROCINFO=["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"   can it be replaced by the line : asort(make,dest_data, "@val_num_desc")? If so , does the for loop remain the same? (Just learning).

Comment: @MarioPelletier I haven't used `asort()` in a long time so I'd suggest you do the same thing I'd have to do to answer your question ... make the change and see if it works; *When in doubt, try it out!* :-)

Answer (score 1):

One in GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '
{
    a[$1][$3][++c[$1,$3]]=$0
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"
    for(i in a) {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
        for(j in a[i]) {
            PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
            for(k in a[i][j])
                print a[i][j][k]
        }
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
toyota          corolla     1995        95000       2
maruti          esteem      1997        98000       1
maruti          swift       2007        50000       5
...
```